# Simple AJAX ~ Viewport Width to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fetch

I want to pass screen width (viewport) to a PHP variable.
I am not familiar with AJAX but as I understand this is the proper way to do it.

I run my website (Coding a WordPress theme) in a local server at the moment (XAMPP) & getting the following error when I try to pass the JS variable to PHP.

POST http://localhost/ 404 (Not Found)

Below is the AJAX part of the code:

```
<?php
    // Handle AJAX request (start)
    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && isset($_POST['name'])) {
        echo $_POST['name'];
        echo "test";
        exit;
    }
    // Handle AJAX request (end)
    ?>
    <!-- Script -->
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

                var ViewPort = $(window).width();
                console.log(ViewPort)

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        ajax: 1,
                        name: ViewPort
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#response').text('name: ' + response);
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
```

Additionally, I don't want to use jQuery since I load it(jQuery) on the footer & the changes based on the viewport need to be applied first.

If you could guide me through this I'll be grateful

Comment: You probably want to post that data to some specific file and not to index.php in your document root (which doesn't seem to exist). Also, what exactly are you expecting to do with that variable? You say _"the changes based on the viewport need to be applied first."_, what changes? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The page will probably be rendered before your Ajax request is done anyway. Regarding Ajax without jQuery, you can use the native [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) API to make ajax requests

Comment: Before you create your own logic that goes completely outside of how such things (AJAX requests) _should_ be handled in WordPress, I would suggest you take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins and https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/

Comment: @M.Eriksson I was thinking that calling & displaying smaller versions of the images (same images but smaller size) that are displaying on my website on mobile devices could speed up my website. Since the first thing that is loading on my webpage is an intro full-screen image with a CTA button, I want the swap image to take effect first.

Answer (score 0):

Below will take the current screen width, save as a variable, send this variable through to PHP using AJAX then it will return results using JSON based on how the PHP code handles the AJAX POST data it has been sent.

If you want this to be dynamic, in the jQuery script replace the first line

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

with;

```
 $(window).on('resize', function() {
```

Code below, PHP file should be a separate file so it can be fetched by AJAX.

```
 <?php
 header('Content-type: application/json');
 $viewPort = $_POST['viewPort']; // You may want to protect this data using mysqli_real_escape_string
 // Viewports under 800px width
 if (($viewPort) < 800) {
 $response = "small";
 }
 // Viewports over 800px width
 if (($viewPort) > 800) {
 $response = "large";
 }
 // Allow front end to read result
 echo json_encode($response);
 ?>


 //jQuery script
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var viewPort = $(window).width();
 console.log(viewPort); // Check we have the width
 $.ajax({
 url:"somefolder/myPHPfile.php", // Referencing above PHP (should be a separate file)
 method:"POST",
 data:{viewPort:viewPort},
 dataType:"json",
 success:function(a) {
 if (a == "small") {
 console.log("the viewport size is small");
 // Do some other function ??
 }
 if (a == "large") {
 console.log("the viewport size is large");
 // Do some other function ??
 }
 }
 });
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

So I found a solution to my problem without using AJAX. So I wanted to pass screen width to a PHP variable in order to change display images on my website based on the device viewport(desktop or tablet).

I found out that this can be done using srcset.

```
<img class="MainImage" src="<?php echo get_field('main_slider_image')['url']; ?>"
srcset="<?php echo get_field('main_slider_image_mobile')['url']; ?> 835w, <?php echo get_field('main_slider_image')['url']; ?> 836w"
alt="<?php echo get_field('main_slider_image')['alt']; ?>">
```

Comment: That's not the way it should be done. It's not dynamic. What if someone resizes the window? If you don't want to use AJAX, use CSS with media queries. btw if you had explained in your intial post why you wanted screen widths I wouldn't have written my answer.